# What is the meaning of associative array?

Tags: c++, data-structures, associative-array

I'm reading The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference book. In map example:

```
   typedef map<string,float> StringFloatMap;
   StringFloatMap coll;

   //insert some elements into the collection
   coll["VAT"] = 0.15;
   coll["Pi"] = 3.1415;
   coll["an arbitrary number"] = 4983.223;
   coll["Null"] = 0;
```

The author say:

> Here, the index is used as the key and may have any type. This is the interface of an associative array. An associative array is an array in which the index may be of an **arbitrary type**.

Any one could explain me, what **arbitrary type** means in associative array?

Comment: It means _any_. You can create a `std::map` that uses `int` as key, `std::string` (like in your example), or even instances of classes.

Comment: From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arbitrary?s=t) `arbitrary: not assigned a specific value`, basically, the index can be anything; a string, an integer, an object...

Comment: I assume/expect/hope that Josuttis went on to explain the requirements imposed on this **"arbitrary" type**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays are generally indexed by the position of the elements. A simple array - `int x[10]`, has its elements `x[0] ... x[9]`. The index is an unsigned integral value.

The associative container means that the index can be, well, an arbitrary (not necessarily an unsigned integral) type (in this case, an `std::string`).

Answer (score 2):

The distinction is between vectors/arrays, which most people would call *sequence containers*, but which can actually be regarded as *associative containers* with the keys being a complete range of integers from 0 to N.

On the other hand, maps do not place such a restriction on the keys, they can be strings, integers, any type you want (provided of course that there is a sensible equality comparison operator on that type).

Comment: Well I would not consider arrays as associative containers indexed by integers: `map[0]` and `map[1000]` allocate two objects, whereas it's an undefined behavior to use `vector[n]` if `n > vector.size()`.

Comment: The automatic creation semantics of map::operator[] in C++ have *nothing* to do with the theoretical classification of containers in my humble opinion...

Comment: My point (that you share by saying "complete range") is that you cannot use an arbitrary **key** with a vector, only a _sequence_, thus I won't consider it as an associative container.

Comment: It associates integers from that range with values, therefore you can consider it an associative container imho. I don't quite see how integers out of range come into this debate. Maybe we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Indeed my vision on associative containers is without constraints on keys, but I agree this is just my personnal opinion, thanks for letting me understand that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can create a map which matches an arbitrary key type to arbitrary value type.

You can create maps which map `std::string`s to `float`s, `short`s to `YourClass`es or `YourOtherClass` to `YetAnotherClass`.

You could even create an `std::map<void *, void *>` which could map any pointer to any other pointer. Although this would be of questionable use, because there would be no way to find out the type of the data the pointer is pointing to.